# DRF 'create' method deletes fields from 'validated_data'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to realize POST method to create Article object.
I have to provide this body:

```
{
"title": "Sample title",
"link": "https://www.sample.com/"
}
```

And get Article object with auto assigned ID, author_name(current user) and creation_date.
But i got an problem - "create" methor deletes one field - author_name. (See code below)
Finally i get next error msg:

```
IntegrityError at /api/articles/
Error:  Null value in column "author_name_id" with NOT NULL 
DETAIL:  Error row contains (32, Sample title, https://www.sample.com/, 2020-11-08, null).
```

How do i solve my problem?

### models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        name='title',
        max_length=120,
        null=False,
    )
    link = models.URLField(
        name='link',
        unique=True,
        null=False,
    )
    creation_date = models.DateField(
        name='creation_date',
        default=date.today,
        null=False,
    )
    author_name = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='articles',
        null=False,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

### views.py

```
class ArticleView(APIView):
    def post(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            data = {"author_name": request.user}
            data.update(request.data)
            print(request.data)
            serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=data)

            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
            return Response(status=201)
        return Response(status=403)
```

---

request.data >>> {'title': 'Sample title', 'link': 'https://www.sample.com/', 'author_name': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>}

### serializers.py

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
author_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()

```
class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = "__all__"


def create(self, validated_data):
    print(validated_data)
    return Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

---

validated_data >>> {'title': 'Sample title', 'link': 'https://www.sample.com/'}

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the `author_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()` you have on your serializers. By default this is a read-only field so the serializer will remove it from the data you pass to it.
I'm pretty sure if you would just do:

```
serializer = ArticleSerializer(request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(author_name=request.user)
```

this should solve your problem. Because on the serializer you validate the fields that are not read-only and then you save the data by passing the user instance to the save method of the serializer.

I also see you are using an ApiView for creating a model instance, I would recommend looking into [CreateApiView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview)